# How can i change the icon color to some other color in CSS?

Tags: html, css

I want to change this icon color via CSS:

[image]

Comment: If this is an svg icon, you can use `color` propert to change color for svg icons.

Comment: Please update your question to contain the relevant code and ask your question here, rather than via a link

Comment: I didn't try this,I am just asking.

Comment: Can you provide example for this.

Comment: Please go through [ask] a Question on StackOverflow.

Comment: " This question is completely unclear, incomplete, overly-broad, primarily opinion-based or is not about programming as described in the help center, and it is unlikely to be fixed via editing. "

Comment: You can consider using filters by -webkit-filter and filter: In this way you can change an image to grayscale, sepia, de saturate and so on.

Comment: If you are talking about grayscale, it is easy.

Comment: Sorry for inconvenience, I am new to Stack overflow so please adjust me.

Comment: Can any one provide Example of using SVG icon

Comment: Check this llink https://css-tricks.com/using-svg/

Answer (score -1):

How about this? From [this site](http://www.w3schools.com/css/css3_images.asp)

```
<!DOCTYPE html>
<html>
<head>
<style>
img {
    width: 33%;
    height: auto;
    float: left;
    max-width: 235px;
    background-color: #12569a;
}


.blur {-webkit-filter: blur(4px);filter: blur(4px);}
.brightness {-webkit-filter: brightness(250%);filter: brightness(250%);}
.contrast {-webkit-filter: contrast(180%);filter: contrast(180%);}
.grayscale {-webkit-filter: grayscale(100%);filter: grayscale(100%);}
.huerotate {-webkit-filter: hue-rotate(180deg);filter: hue-rotate(180deg);}
.invert {-webkit-filter: invert(100%);filter: invert(100%);}
.opacity {-webkit-filter: opacity(50%);filter: opacity(50%);}
.saturate {-webkit-filter: saturate(7); filter: saturate(7);}
.sepia {-webkit-filter: sepia(100%);filter: sepia(100%);}
.shadow {-webkit-filter: drop-shadow(8px 8px 10px green);filter: drop-shadow(8px 8px 10px green);}
</style>
</head>
<body>

<p><strong>Note:</strong> The filter property is not supported in Internet Explorer, Edge 12, or Safari 5.1 and earlier.</p>

<img src="https://i.stack.imgur.com/W8L0k.png" alt="Pineapple" width="300" height="300">
<img class="blur a" src="https://i.stack.imgur.com/W8L0k.png" alt="Pineapple" width="300" height="300">
<img class="brightness a" src="https://i.stack.imgur.com/W8L0k.png" alt="Pineapple" width="300" height="300">
<img class="contrast a" src="https://i.stack.imgur.com/W8L0k.png" alt="Pineapple" width="300" height="300">
<img class="grayscale a" src="https://i.stack.imgur.com/W8L0k.png" alt="Pineapple" width="300" height="300">
<img class="huerotate a" src="https://i.stack.imgur.com/W8L0k.png" alt="Pineapple" width="300" height="300">
<img class="invert a" src="https://i.stack.imgur.com/W8L0k.png" alt="Pineapple" width="300" height="300">
<img class="opacity a" src="https://i.stack.imgur.com/W8L0k.png" alt="Pineapple" width="300" height="300">
<img class="saturate a" src="https://i.stack.imgur.com/W8L0k.png" alt="Pineapple" width="300" height="300">
<img class="sepia a" src="https://i.stack.imgur.com/W8L0k.png" alt="Pineapple" width="300" height="300">
<img class="shadow a" src="https://i.stack.imgur.com/W8L0k.png" alt="Pineapple" width="300" height="300">

</body
```

>

[image]